# Is there an embedded SQL DB on Windows Phone Mango?

Tags: database, windows-phone-7

Does WP 7.5 comes with a ready to use SQL DB of some kind on board?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, [SQLite for WP7](http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/) is the only available option.

Comment: So it's just the client for a remote database? WP7.1 doesn't have an RDBMS running in it?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov No, it's a full database that stores the database in IsolatedStorage. There is nothing out-of-box, however.

Answer (score 1):

With WP 7.5/Mango comes support for [local database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202865%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) which uses a SQL Server Compact 3.5 database. The development model is based on LINQ to SQL.